# Auto hide bottom sheet when value changes from Firestore stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I have a modal bottom sheet open waiting for a player to join a game via a code. I have a stream set up in my controller. When the player joins, I get the name of the other player. Once I get this name, I want to programmatically dismiss the bottom sheet so that the game can begin.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Could you please elaborate an answer with the steps taken to help other users that have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the modal is on top, you can simply call the following to close it:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

So, call this whenever you receive your data.

Comment: I ended up using a StreamBuilder to solve it.

Comment: @Stephen Said: Could you please elaborate an answer with the steps taken to help other users that have similar issues.